# Programmatically using python, import grafana dashboard data from grafana website

Tags: python, rest, grafana, grafana-api

I have a visual and aggregate result showin in grafana.<<my_company>>.com. I can manually go to the menu click export and export the  data to my local in format option I have. This works great. Is there a way I can script that in python that hit grafana server and get result what I need ? So that I can automate it.
Looking for info thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

W can use wrapper library as in https://pypi.org/project/grafana-api/.

With requests library a sample snippet is pasted below,

```
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {os.getenv('GRAFANA_TOKEN')}"}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers
r = s.get(grafana_url + "/api/search?query=&", headers=headers)
dashboards = r.json()
print(dashboards)

dashboard_dir = f"dashboards_{grafana_server}"
if not os.path.isdir(dashboard_dir):
    os.makedirs(dashboard_dir)
for entry in dashboards:
    if entry["type"] != "dash-db":
        continue
    print(entry["uid"])
    try:
        url = grafana_url + f"/api/dashboards/uid/{entry['uid']}"
        print(url)
        r = s.get(url)
        data = r.json()
        filename = dashboard_dir + "/" + data["meta"]["slug"] + ".json"
        with open(filename, "w") as fd:
            json.dump(data, fd, indent=4)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Also to create dashboards through codes refer - https://github.com/weaveworks/grafanalib/tree/main/grafanalib/tests/examples

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Grafana HTTP API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/).

There is also explained, [how to get a dashboard by using the dashboards uid](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/dashboard/#get-dashboard-by-uid).
In python, you can for example use the [requests package](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make http requests.
In the JSON response you're getting for the linked request, `dashboard` will provide the data you are looking for.